# Why does AngularJS put HTTP PUT data in URL instead of body?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two services:

```
var PlanResource = $resource('/api/v1/plan/:planId', {}, {
  'update':  { method:'PUT', params:{ planId : '@_id.$oid' }, isArray : false },
});
```

and

```
var UserResource = $resource('/api/v1/user', {}, {
    'update': {method:'PUT', params:{ }, isArray : false},
});
```

When I call update on the first it puts the data I pass in the body where as the second puts the data in the URL for example:

```
PUT /api/v1/user?profiles=%7B%22skeleton%22:false,%data%22:234
```

Why does this happen, and how can I get the second to put the data in the body?

EDIT:

Usage is:

```
ctrl.user.$update({'profiles' : appCtrl.user.profiles}).then(function() {
```

and

```
ctrl.plan.$update({name: planName});
```

Comment: usually means the contentType is not set properly... can you check the request in the network tab of browser developer tools and check the request headers

Comment: Both have: Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: There aren't any parameter it's to update the currently logged in user. So there is only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you show the code of your usage?

Generally, you should not put any value that you intend to put in the body into the "params". They should belong to a separate argument. In the $resource document, there is

```
non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
```

So you should try sth like:

```
UserResource.update({
    // URL params here.
}, profiles   // Body here.
, ..., ...);
```

#### EDIT:

As you updated, you are using instance methods instead of class methods. In the doc, it says:

```
non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
```

In an instance method call, you can only pass in URL parameters. The body of the request would automatically be the object itself (in your case, **ctrl.user** would be the body).

If you really want to modify the request body to something other than the object itself, please use the class methods instead.

The doc for $resource is here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I added the way it's called